# AHK v2 mouse clicking loop

Tags: autohotkey

```
global toggleVar := false

>^j::
{
    global toggleVar :=! toggleVar
}

if (WinActive("Warframe") and toggleVar = true)
{
    while (GetKeyState("LButton")) 
    {   
        Click
        Sleep 250
    }
}
```

I am absolute noob in autohotkey, installed it today, also got scared by a bunch of viruses. Anyways, I wanted to have a toggle variable and when I'm in a game I want to hold down LMB and it will continue clicking for me. But it does nothing and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1):

```
#HotIf WinActive("Warframe")

    >^j::
    {
        static toggle := 0

        HotIf 'WinActive("Warframe")'                                        ; change the hotkey context for Hotkey function
        Hotkey "LButton", SpamClick, (toggle := !toggle) ? "On" : "Off"      ; enable or disable lbutton hotkey

        SpamClick(ThisHotkey) {
            while GetKeyState("LButton", "P") {
                Click
                Sleep 250
            }
        }
    }

#HotIf
```

Apparently this is how it's supposed to be done, it worked for me. Thanks to "plankoe" from reddit.

Comment: You didn't say that you have Autohotkey v2